# XSLT 2.0 for-each count up

Tags: xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

I have to itterate over the xml items and make some math each row

```
<items>
<item amount="12">
<item amount="13">
<item amount="14">
</items>
```

i have already tried to assign this to global variables or make a function. both does not work for me.

so now i want after each line the sum of the amount. how can i do that with xslt-2.0. assigning to global variables does not work.

Comment: What is your expected result? Do you want accumulated subtotals for each line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *i want after each line the sum of the amount*.

If you want to print the *accumulated sum* of all the previous amounts, you can use a XPath expression, in the context of each `item`, such as:

```
sum(preceding-sibling::item/@amount | @amount)
```

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="items">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        <subtotal>
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(preceding-sibling::item/@amount | @amount)"/>
        </subtotal>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

applied to your example case will produce:

```
<items>
    <item amount="12"/><subtotal>12</subtotal>
    <item amount="13"/><subtotal>25</subtotal>
    <item amount="14"/><subtotal>39</subtotal>
</items>
```